# Where do you think this question might go on stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, site-rec

This is the question:

[In my situation, how could I learn to program without a mentor?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313233/in-my-situation-how-could-i-learn-to-program-without-a-mentor)

It appears to be off-topic here, I've made a mistake assuming this site is about all things programming. Is there a site in the roster that this quesiton fits?

Comment: related: [Where to ask for general advice for young programmers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216617/165773)

Comment: Ask here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com stay away from this crazy site.

Answer (score 1):

Try [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), the sites chat room.

That sort of question really doesn't fit a Q/A site, but more of a discussion type of format - chat is a great place for that.

I can say from personal experience that The Whiteboard has greatly benefited me as a programmer.